# Get value of dictionaries into separate lists

Tags: python

I am trying to get array by first key.
The names of the keys are always the same and the number of elements is the same.

```
[{'a': 1, 'b':41, 'c':324}, {'a': 1, 'b':12, 'c':65}, {'a': 2, 'b':36, 'c':12}]
```

expected output:

```
[{'b':41, 'c':324}, {'b':12, 'c':65}]
[{'b':36, 'c':12}]
```

Comment: i think u mean output - `[[{'b':41, 'c':324}, {'b':12, 'c':65}], [{'b':36, 'c':12}]]`

Comment: what do you mean by "get array by first key"?

Answer (score 2):

Make a new dictionary that uses the values of the `a` keys as its keys.

```
newdict = {}

for d in data:
    newdict.setdefault(d['a'], []).append({'b': d['b'], 'c': d['c']})

result = list(new_dict.values())
```